# Best way to show if a user's friends are using this app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an Android app which is social in nature, so an important part is for the users to be able to invite their friends and add them as friends inside the app.

I'm unsure of the best way to go about doing this. For example, say the user can select a friend from his contacts. In this case, I can send a link to Google Play/Apple App Store so he can download the app and also store that would be sent to this contact via email or SMS.

I've created a backend which manages the user's posts and groups, and would also keep track of friendships and such.

1. What's the best way to find out and show the user if his friends are connected?

   1a. I can get the user's friend list from Facebook, but not their emails, so is there any way to uniquely identify one of his Facebook friends?

   1b. I can read the user's phone contacts and get their emails and compare it to the registered emails on the server, but could there be privacy implications?

Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Best would be to integrate everything, Google plus, Facebook, phone book.

1a. You can not get other user emails but you can get the user id, you would need to have several db entries with both emails and facebook user-ids for recognition of friends having or not having the app.

1b. Make sure you do not save their emails and say so explicitly in the Terms-of-Use, so that users do not get spooked

Side note: emails collected from facebook can not be read from your phonebook which can be confusing for users when they have an e-mail for their friend in their phonebook but your app can't see it